# AngularJS and Firebase not showing the $id

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to do an application that tracks attendees' approval of a speech or similar. I am facing a challenge which holds me off for now several hours.

Here is the js file

```
angular.module('speechAssessment', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

.value('fbURL', 'https://XXXX.firebaseio.com/')

.factory('Attendees', function($firebase, fbURL) {
   return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL));
})

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller:'ListCtrl',
      templateUrl:'partials/list1.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/'
    });
})

.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, Attendees) {
  $scope.attendees = Attendees;
});
```

As you can see, I stripped the app to the bare minimum. I am getting data from Firebase and bring it into the $scope.attendees.

the html looks like

```
<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | orderByPriority">
      <p>{{attendee.name}}:{{attendee.score}}:{{attendee.$id}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I list all attendees and list some attributes, among them the $id from Firebase

So, a typical row looks like

roestigraben:-45:-JTI2DALNZXxltukIHcY

Now the application shows correct results until I remove the | orderByPriority filter. Doing so, the application runs but does not show the $id any longer. I cannot understand why this Filter has anything to do with the listing of the $id. 
Can somebody shade some light on this for me, please. Really appreciated.

Comment: What version is this?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular-resource.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular-route.min.js">
   </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

Comment: AngularFire is on version 0.8 now. This is probably a bug in an earlier version. The source of the problem is likely that the conversion from an object to an array--the $id attribute would exist on the object, not the newly generated array.

Comment: I did a version update to angular with 1.3.0-beta.17, firebase to 1.0.18 and angularfire to 0.8.0. But no success, unfortunately.